# How to auto refresh the contents from custom adapter when its data depends on another class?

Tags: android, listadapter, android-adapterview

I am trying to change the view from one class when the data changes in another class using `notifyDataSetChanged()` on custom adapter.

`Class FragmentOne` starts thread where `listItems` are added.

Then I am using `class FragmentTwo` and getting those `listItems` and updating my view.

My code---

**Class FragmentOne**

```
static ArrayList<String> listItems = null;

private class MonitorLogThread extends Thread
{
    BufferedReader br;

    @Override
    public void run() {

while(((line=br.readLine()) != null) && !this.isInterrupted()){
   listItems.add(line);
}
 }
```

**Class FragmentTwo**

```
private BBLogListAdapter mBBLogListAdapter;
ArrayList<String> receiptlist;

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  

     if(receiptlist == null)
        receiptlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    else
        receiptlist.clear();

    // Initializes list view adapter.
    mBBLogListAdapter = new BBLogListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mBBLogListAdapter);

    mBBLogListAdapter.updateReceiptsList(FragmentOne.listItems);

    mBBLogListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

        // Custom Adapter
        private class BBLogListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
             //Code to set view dynamically according to data in adapter
             public void updateReceiptsList(ArrayList<String> newlist) {
             receiptlist.clear();
             receiptlist.addAll(newlist);
        }

        //Some more code..
      }
}
```

So, currently I am using method updateReceiptsList in the method onResume() to update the 
contents. This only updates when we resume the activity.

But I want to auto refresh the contents while in this activity according to data change from another activity.

Comment: Doesn't calling notifyDataSetChanged on mBBLogListAdapter object whenever the data has changed work?

Comment: It works whenever I resume my activity because I am calling it at `onResume()`. Where to call this so that it work all the time I am on activity ? Do I need a broadcast receiver to notify the change and then update ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grab a hold of your adapter object and create a static method in "FragmentTwo",

```
public static void notifyDataChanged(){
  if(mBBLogListAdapter != null){
       mBBLogListAdapter.updateReceiptsList(FragmentOne.listItems);
       mBBLogListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

Whenever your data changes in your thread call this static method.

```
static ArrayList<String> listItems = null;

private class MonitorLogThread extends Thread
{
  BufferedReader br;

 @Override
 public void run() {

while(((line=br.readLine()) != null) && !this.isInterrupted()){
 listItems.add(line);

 FragmentTwo.notifyDataChanged();
 }
}
```

Note that, you need to use the same adapter object that you used to setAdapter in FragmentTwo's onResume

```
setListAdapter(mBBLogListAdapter);
```

PS: A cleaner alternative would be to use a listener on "FragmentTwo" that listens to any data changes on "FragmentOne". See here for implementation details - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will cause concurrent access to a non thread safe object. This will also can cause IllegalStateExceptions.

Comment: mBBLogListAdapter is null when I call notifyDataChanged.

Comment: Because update happens on a different thread, you should add a null check to make sure the adapter has been initialized in the first place before calling notifyDataSetChanged. I will edit to add this null check

Answer (score 1):

Correct approach to this kind of problem is to use `ContentProvider`s and `CursorAdapter`s. When the data is changed your adapter will be notified and all the synchronization will be handled by the Framework itself. Less pain, more gain.

Comment: Wouldn't using an Event Listener on FragmentTwo for a event when data has changed in FragmentOne work also?

Comment: You are introducing too much state dependency to your fragments by doing so. You gotta know that your fragments, activities and any context can be shut down by Android OS ***anytime***. You can't just assume that UI components will be there for you. Because of that you gotta persist any data if you are planning to use on UI.

Comment: I am not interacting with database at all. I am getting data from some process command and then calling notifyDataSetChanged. So why to use ContentProviders and CursorAdapters ?

Comment: What I mean is you *should*. You should persist your data as often as feasibly possible.

Comment: This isn't the data to persist into database. These are the system logs that change all the time. I just want to show the recent ones in a view on notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: You can still use a local database for this. Your cursor can provide only latest and you can purge the old logs. I suggest a system where one producer and one consumer exists. Producer reads data from logs, and puts it to database, consumer shows that data, using CursorAdapters and ContentProvider. This will give you a lot of flexibility. By tying two classes together you are creating too much coupling. This will eventually cause problems.